# REST service return

Tags: java, rest, service

I have made a REST client-server, and everything works more or less fine. Here is the dilemma: I have an option to retrieve user by its username, which works fine when the user actually exists. However, when he doesn't, i get 204 http code, which is fine, since I made a null return. I would like my method to return a plain string to client console when no user is found, say, "No such user found...", but the method return type is User (class) logically, to return a user object when such is found.
Here is the server side:

```
@GET
    @Path("/{uName}")
    @Produces({ "application/json", "application/xml"})
    public User getUserByUsername(@PathParam("uName") String uName) {

        returnAll = usrList.getUsers();

        for (User u : returnAll) {
            if (u.getUserName().equals(uName))
                return u;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

And here is the relevant part of client:

```
        case 3:
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter username");
            userName = sc.nextLine();

            restConnect("http://localhost:8080/rest/user/"
                    + userName, "GET");

            promptKey();
```

Changing a method to return a String type would obviously disrupt the code when user is actually found. What can I do to make two type return function? Thanks

EDIT:
When user was found, my method would return the first user in list with `get(0)` which is wrong. It was a residue of me testing something with the ID's

EDITx2: working client

```
        case 3:
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter username");
            userName = sc.nextLine();

            try{
            restConnect("http://localhost:8080/rest/user/"
                    + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8"), "GET");
            }
            catch(RuntimeException e){
                System.out.println("No such user...");
            }
            promptKey();
```

Comment: Why not throw exception and http status say 500? Or Why not make use of NullObjectPattern and return dummy user instead?

Comment: Because I want a user-friendly information :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be returning a 4xx error when the user does not exist and the client should have a branch when an error is returned.

Think about how things should work for a client that you did not develop yourself and the definition of the API will probably be more clear.

See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html for additional result code details.

Comment: I have made a try/catch block in the client section, which catches a runtime exception. It works now as I want it to, however, is this a good approach?

Comment: If ```restConnect``` throws an exception when a 4xx error is returned, then yes, that's what you want.